# When Connection reset happens will Salesforce takes care of resubmitting the API?

Tags: soap, salesforce

We are using soap API call to send request. Some time I will see Connection Reset exception.

When this happens, in our code we have retry logic, when it sees this exception it retires to send the same API call for 5 times in 30 secs (default). But both parameter is configurable.

My question is, if Salesforce take cares of resubmitting the API which had connection reset error., then sending same API call from client side will duplicate the data right?

is there any way we can take care from client side code, so that if data has been already submitted by Salesforce server, we should not send that API again with same data.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce doesn't retry inbound SOAP requests, you have to do it yourself.